Auto Rig Pro - Attach the Kilt/Skirt Rig to an existing Custom Character Rig and get a good result
I'm in the process of rigging a character in Blender. The rig is custom-made from scratch, as I followed Dikko's character rigging tutorial series for most of it.
My character has a skirt, and the skirt doesn't have a very robust rig, so I decided to use the Auto Rig Pro add-on to attach the built-in kilt/skirt rig to my Character Rig.
Since my character doesn't use the Auto Rig Pro Human Rig, I decided to spawn in an Empty Rig instead so I can add a Skirt rig to attach to my character.

Then I join the empty ARP rig with my custom character rig, it says I'll have to update, so I did.

Once that's done, I add the Kilt setup from the Limbs menu. It's much smaller than the character though, so I just scale it up in Edit Mode

After that I align the bones to the skirt and then I select "Match To Rig" and parent the Skirt to the new Bones.

Now, here comes that part that I'm especially having difficulty with. The process of adding Collision to the Skirt.
I click on "Edit Reference Bones" and choose the Limb Options, and assign the Leg Bones that the skirt will Collide With.

In ARP, when you attach the Kilt to an ARP Human Rig, there would be these Sliders for the Kilt Bones, where you can control the collision and there would also be Secondary Bones for more adjustment options.

But on MY Empty with Kilt Rig joined with Custom Character Rig, these don't show up, why is that? That's the difficulty I'm having here.

Is there a way for me to add Auto Rig Pro's Skirt Rig to a Custom Character Rig without using the ARP Human Rig?
